# Electron with local https server, redirecting POST request fails pre-flight OPTIONS

Tags: node.js, https, cors, electron, webrequest

I have a web app wrapped with electron. The electron app filters web requests and redirects them to handle by local `https` server.

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest({urls:["*://capture.api.url/*"]}, (details, callback) => {
// here all matching filter requests will end up e.g. https://capture.api.url/test

    const url = new URL(details.url);
// redirect to the local https server
    callback({
      redirectURL: `https://localhost:12345${url.pathname}${url.search}${url.hash}`
    });
});
```

This bit works but only for `GET` method, request is then handled by the server

```
    const httpsOptions = {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "server-key.pem")),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "server-cert.pem"))
    };
    this.server = https.createServer(
      httpsOptions,
      (req /* : IncomingMessage */, res /* : ServerResponse */) => {
            // add CORS headers
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader(
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
              "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS"
            );
            res.setHeader(
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
              "Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"
            );
            // handle request...
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end();
      }
    );
    this.server.listen(port);
```

This work like I've mentioned for a `GET` request, but for `POST` the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request is issued. Which is then redirected and it fails without even reaching my local server with following error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://capture.api.url/search' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Worth to mention is that it happens during development, where web app is build and run on separate process and served on `localhost:3001` and electron app is loading the app from that endpoint.

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
      isDevMode ? "http://localhost:3001" : `file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`
    );
```

It works fine (so far) when it is not a dev mode. Is there a way to disable this preflight check? Or correct it somehow so it doesnt fail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work, however I'm not sure this is the right way

```
  // Define our main window size
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 920,
    width: 1600,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {

      // turn off webSecurity when in dev mode
      webSecurity: !isDevMode,



      allowEval: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(
        __dirname,
        "node_modules",
        "@capacitor",
        "electron",
        "dist",
        "electron-bridge.js"
      )
    }
  });
```

I will still wait for other answers, in the meantime I'll use this "hack".

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue in react-electron app with axios. I am using electron v11.0.5.  Above solution is not working for me.